# How to include and link to external javadocs

Tags: javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm currently generating javadocs for a project which relies heavily on some external libraries such as guava. All of the dependencies are listed in the pom.xml and to avoid having to manually update links every time a library version is changed I'd like to generate/download the javadocs for all of our dependencies and link to local versions of the javadocs for the external libraries in the project's javadocs.

I've seen `<offlineLinks>` and I don't believe this solves the entire issue however it's very well possible I'm missing something here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<links>` in your javadoc configuration. You can find more documentation on how to use it [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/links-configuration.html)

A few things to note:

1. For me, the external links worked only with `maven-javadoc-plugin` version 3.1.0 and not with 3.0.1
2. All external links should have a downloadable `package-list` file i.e. if you have added a link https://example.com/apidocs/, then there should be a file downloadable at https://example.com/apidocs/package-list